# How to filter an iron-list in polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-1.x, iron-elements

The `dom-repeat` element offers a `filter` attribute.

Is there a similar way to filter with `iron-list`?

For example: Given a list of people, I want to filter the ones born in a specific city.

Comment: sounds like a task for backend

Comment: You might want to study [`iron-data-table`](https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/). https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As `iron-list` unfortunately doesn't offer a `filter` attribute, there is no declarative pattern making this possible.

You can either implement your own simple list element making use of `dom-repeat`'s filter property. (With element inheritance coming back in future releases, you might extend `iron-list`).

However, the best practice I currently see is the use of a computed property:

```
<template>
  <iron-list items="[[filterItems(items)]]" as="item">
    ...
  </iron-list>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
  ...
  filterItems: function (items) {
    return items.filter(function (item) { // Array.prototype.filter
      return item.priority > 8; // Filter condition
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: suppose if I have a search bar and on typing letters in search input, then what I need to for filtering? should I add an observer 'filterItems' to search input property?

Comment: can someone elaborate this solution??

Comment: there are search components in webcomponents.org for searching. You may want to look into those as well. But to me it seems like you can use observers rather than computed properties and just set the items in there whenever your input changes. Also, a search bar most likely has an input which you may be able to use the on-change event of input and do your work there